# Why has Poland called up the military reserve?

Tags: ukraine, poland

Why has Poland called up the reserve of two hundred thousand when their existing manpower is one hundred and fifty thousand?

Polish president Duda has suddenly visited the Ukrainian city of Lviv. [Some political commentators believe](https://youtu.be/Ts-BVW6ujT8) he was there to assess the local mindset about Poland.

Comment: Hello 355312,  you know the score:  When you say "Some commentator say..." include the link to the source -  Don't ask if Poland will invade Western Ukraine.  Because nobody can see the future.

Comment: In particular, does your source say the same as mine  https://www.thefirstnews.com/article/poland-plans-to-draft-200000-for-military-training-next-year-34974   "**up to** 200,000"  (this is a regulation allowing up to that number but the actual number recalled will be " 28,580 voluntary military service people and up to 38,000 active reservists."

Comment: @user366312 What is the difference in connotation between Poland calling up their reserves, and Belarus calling up theirs? For that matter, Russia calling up theirs?

Comment: Are you looking for a more specific answer than "the Russian invasion of Ukraine"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This doesn't seem unusual compared to the previous years. I didn't watch the lengthy show to see exactly what claims are made there, [but](https://www.polskieradio.pl/395/7784/Artykul/3084221,poland-to-train-200000-reservists-in-2023-officials):

> Up to 200,000 reservists will be called up for military training in Poland next year, officials have said.
>
> The figure is roughly the same as in 2021 and 2022, according to a draft decree by the defence ministry, Polish state news agency PAP reported.

Comment: Poland is also looking to expand its armed forces; after the 2022 Russian invasion of Ukraine, Poland [announced](https://archive.is/rIMqX) they intend to grow their armed forces to 300,000 (of which 250,000 professionals and 50,000 [WOT] territorials) by 2035, i.e. some decade+ from now.

Comment: But the actual recruitment this year [was](https://polanddaily24.com/polish-mod-wants-an-increase-of-territorial-defence-forces-to-50000/politics/17655) around 13,700 and even that is not necessarily a net increase; people also retire/quit the army (and those figures are not mentioned in that piece). "Poland now has about 36,000 WOT troops and around 128,000 soldiers of various formations".